# Is there a word for an envious person?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, pejorative-language

Is "Envier" a word? I don't quite think it is :-/

And I know you can describe him as a jealous person..But that's again an adjective.

I'm looking for something like - You call a person who is extremely greedy when it comes to food, a 'Gourmand' or a 'Glutton'.

Comment: jealous != envious ... and [envier](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/envy?q=envier#envy__5) does exist

Comment: envious >= jealous :) It's a synonym.
http://thesaurus.com/browse/envious?__utma=1.919820829.1343153875.1343153875.1343153875.1&__utmb=1.4.9.1343154618412&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1343153875.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=11163700

Comment: "Envier: one that envies. First known use: 15th century." — [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envier?show=0&t=1343154589)

Comment: I guess the difference between jealous and envious is, that being jealous mean to be frightened to lose something (e.g. the girl-/boyfriend, when other guys are talking to them) while envious just mean that you want to have something that do other have (e.g. a girl-/boyfriend when you haven't one). Thus jealous != envious; and you should never mix them up

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA
Well,I'll be... o.O ...How did I miss that?! Thanks :) I'll happy to settle for this if I don't get any other possible synonyms.

Comment: I was wondering about "coveter." It doesn't appear to be in the dictionary, but that wouldn't stop me from using it :)

Comment: @JAM: It [does](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coveter) exist as does [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/begrudger) and possibly more.

Comment: "Exwife". yep, that would do it! :)